# How to pull configuration settings from XML file in Startup.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a startup.cs file and i want to pull configurations from XML file rather than `appsetings.json` file. Is it possible with ASP.NET Core MVC?

Answer (score 13):

If you want to use an `appsettings.xml` instead you can refer to my blog article [here](https://joonasw.net/view/asp-net-core-1-configuration-deep-dive).

Quote from the article:

> To use XML files, you need to add this NuGet package:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml. I added the 1.0.0 to my
>   project.json and added a appsettings.xml file.
>
> `<configuration>
>     <MySettings>
>       <SomeSetting>Test</SomeSetting>
>       <Another>true</Another>
>     </MySettings>
>   </configuration>`
>
> I then added it as part of configuration like this:
>
> `.AddXmlFile("appsettings.xml", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)`

Comment: @junnas : Thank you for the answer. Can you please show me the startup constructor as whole. because i am not able to have .AddXM() method using configurationbuilder object

Comment: You have to add the package I mentioned to project.json

Comment: The namespace does not support the framework DNX . version 5.0

Comment: Are you using .net core 1.0 or higher?