# Reading app.config from .NET Standard 2.0 library

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, app-config, .net-standard-2.0

I'm creating a .NET Standard 2.0 library to be consumed from a .NET Framework 4.6.1 application.
This library needs EF Core, but I can't figure out how to read the app.config.

In a .NET Framework library I would initialize my DBContext like this:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString);
}
```

But I can't do it since ConfigurationManager is nowhere to be found in .NET Standard 2.0.
How can I read the configuration file from a .NET Standard 2.0 library?

Comment: `.NET Core`/`.NET Standard` is more used to `JSON` files than `XML`. If you need to read XML files, you have to add a reference to the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40036819/how-to-pull-configuration-settings-from-xml-file-in-startup-cs) for more details

Comment: Why are you reading an XML configuration file (a .NET Framework concept) in a .NET Standard library? That's not particularly portable. Nor, for that matter, is it a good idea to read settings from a library, even on the regular .NET Framework. Have the connection string injected by the application instead; it can read its configuration file without trouble.

Comment: You can accept a `DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>` in the constructor to do what @JeroenMostert mentions

Answer (score 7):

Create an interface and use dependency inversion for the connection string, so your code will look something like

```
public interface IConnectionSettings
{
    string MyDatabaseConnectionString { get; }
}

class MyClass
{
    private readonly IConnectionSettings _connectionSettings;

    public MyClass(IConnectionSettings connectionSettings)
    {
        _connectionSettings = connectionSettings;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionSettings.MyDatabaseConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Then the consuming app running in .NET Framework can then create their own settings implementation and pass it in

```
public class ConfigurationManagerConnectionSettings : IConnectionSettings
{
    public string MyDatabaseConnectionString { get; }
        = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;
}

var s = new ConfigurationManagerConnectionSettings();
var myClass = new MyClass(s);
```

And all the hipster kids can use environment variables:

```
public class EnvironmentVariableConnectionSettings : IConnectionSettings
{
    public string MyDatabaseConnectionString { get; }
        = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyDatabaseConnectionString");
}
```

Win for everyone