# Is there s single switch in ASP.Net Core to use XML configuration?

Tags: asp.net-core

In ASP.Net Core there are configuration files in JSON by default. It's a real annoyance as JSON does not support comments and is therefore pretty inappropriate for configuration files (as already proved by frontend tools, which prefer javascript configuration). I believe it is only for the simplest demos but it's hardly used for any real scenario project.

I found in documentation I can use `AddXmlFile` on `ConfigurationBuilder` but there must be single switch to even generate new project with XML configuration without having to do it in code.

Comment: .NET Core *doesn't* use any kind of configuration by default. You have to specify what you want *explicitly*. Even JSON config files are added with `AddJson`

Comment: Does this help? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40036819/how-to-pull-configuration-settings-from-xml-file-in-startup-cs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But newly created project contains files appsettings.json and Properties\launchSettings.json. The code does not contain AddJson() - so these files are not used at all?

Comment: @Ichirichi That seems to be outdated - The `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml` is added by default after the project is created. The code in the template does not contain `AddJson()` method.

Comment: I think the simple answer to your question is **no** - You will need to add an Xml configuration source using code. `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` adds support for `.json` but not for `.xml`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Yes, just found it out too. I added `ConfigureAppConfiguration()` to remove the `JsonConfigurationSource` and insert the Xml file. But the problem is that adding Json files is hardcoded in `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder`.  Still wondering why they use JSON (possibly one of the most inappropriate format for configuration files :-( )

Comment: Interestingly I have found .NET Core doesn't care about the // comments I put in my appsettings.json

Comment: @Tubs Oh, funny thing - so it is not JSON anymore?

Comment: @eXavier no, even though it has the .json extension the program can still interpret it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Core utilizes configuration providers. By default, it includes a JSON config provider, an environment variable config provider and a command-line config provider. You are free to add any additional providers you like, or even entirely custom providers you create yourself. An XML configuration provider is not attached by default, and there's no "switch", project template or anything else that will add it. XML is actually a pretty inferior configuration format, so this isn't likely to change, especially since you can always just add it in manually if you want it.

Comment: Accepting as this answers the question. But feel urge to add this comment. I agree XML is not the best format for configuration but pure JSON is even worse as it has been designed for different purpose and any usable configuration file must support comments within the file. As found in the discussion below the question, MS allows comments in ASP.NET Core JSON configuration files (even though I haven't found this in documentation). It is rather pragmatic approach but it is also abuse of the JSON format and strictly it is not [JSON](https://www.json.org/) any more.

Comment: I'd actually argue the opposite. JSON is designed as an object representation format. If you think of your config as an object with members (and such is actually the case when you utilize strongly typed config), it is ideal. Honestly config doesn't need comments anyways. The names of your members should tell all the story necessary.

Comment: Agree on JSON represnts object state. Therefore it is good for (de)serialzation, it can represent configuration snapshot. But you hardly express intent, alternatives, value format, temporary change, etc without comments. Imagine you need temporarily change your configuration until some problem is resolved (which can take weeks even months) and after it is resolved you want back the original config.