System.Configuration App.config file with .NET 8.0
I have an old library that used .NET 4.7.2. It uses System.Configuration and an app.config file.
I migrated the library to target framework of .NET Standard 2.0. My unit tests, I migrated to .NET 8.0.
Now, the test acts as if the app.config file does not exist.
My app.config file is as follows:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Email:ApiKey" value="SG.11111111111"/>
        <!— keys removed ... -->
        <!-- Audit=0, Error = 1, Warning=2, Info=3, Debug=4 -->
        <add key="LogLevel" value="4"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
                <network host="localhost" port="25" enableSsl="false"/>
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
</configuration>

A simple test looks like this:
[TestMethod]
public void ConfigurationManager_AppSettings_Exists_Test()
{
    string _apiKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email:ApiKey"].ToString();
    Assert.AreEqual("SG.11111111111", _apiKey);
}

It errors on the assignment of the variable _apiKey, with the following message:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

It used to work 6 years ago. Does app.config work under .NET 8.0 ?

You can configure a .Net 8 application to use a wide variety of configuration providers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Maybe think about converting the configuration to json, as @topsail mentioned there are a variety of configuration providers but xml is not provided by default. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52151603/is-there-s-single-switch-in-asp-net-core-to-use-xml-configuration

Some of the code base leverages mailSettings features.

The following may be of interest: Configuration in .NET and Configuration providers in .NET

Right-click on App.config and choose Properties. Check that Copy To Output Directory is set to Copy always or Copy if newer. The new framework templates don't set this automatically when adding this file. The older project templates did because they were designed for .NET 4.x, which was configured with App.config or Web.config, so the knew the files needed to be copied to the output directory. This assumption goes away in the new framework, since those applications are typically configured using AppSettings.json.

I set it to 'Copy always', I see it in the NSG.Library_Tests\bin\Debug\net8.0 folder, no change, it's returns still null.  I also see 'NSG.Library_Tests.dll.config' file.  The content of both is the same.

Per ConfigurationManager Class it is available in .Net 8.0.   var _appSettings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings; returns a collection of count 0.

In my opinion, it works in net48, but doesn't work in netcoreapp3.0, net6.0 or net8.0.  I'm using System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager version 8.0.0 in all of them.

I think the supportedRuntime property of the app.config tells it all, version v4.8.  Since this is the Test project of a bunch of net standard libraries, I'm just changing it net48 and not net8.0.
